# How to get a specific column from the joined table in HasMany relationship in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

My Model looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class appraisaltask extends Model
{
    //
     protected $table = 'empappraisaltask';

    /*
     * An invoice can has many payments 
     *
     */
     public function ratings(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\appraisalrating','empappraisaltask_id')->select(array('comment', 'rating'));
    }
}
```

and I am doing a query in my function like this

```
 public function getUserbasictask(){

        $taskwithcomments = appraisaltask::select(array('id','taskname','description','status'))->with(  array('ratings' => function($query)
          {
             // the condition that will be apply on the with relation
              $query->where('emp_id','=',Auth::user()->empid);

          }))->where('type','=','basic')->get();

            return json_encode($taskwithcomments);
    }
```

But I am getting Empty `Rating` object . ANy suggestion how to do that

If I remove the `select()` from the rating function in the model I get all the details

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i got your issue,update your ratings function in appraisaltask model

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\appraisalrating','empappraisaltask_id')->select(array('emp_id','comment', 'rating'));
}
```

and also update query

```
 public function getUserbasictask(){
    $taskwithcomments = appraisaltask::select(array('id','taskname','description','status'))
->with(['ratings' => function($query)
      {
         // the condition that will be apply on the with relation
          $query->where('emp_id','=',Auth::user()->empid);

      }])->where('type','=','basic')->get();

        return json_encode($taskwithcomments);
}
```

hope it will work.

Comment: explain your answer please and this is not working as well same as before

Comment: emp_id is the attribute of appraisalrating table? right.

Comment: ratings relationship getting only comment and rating attr and in query you are applying condition on emp_id which is not selected.